# Redcap: Auto-Incrementing redcap_repeat_instance Field Without Pre-Population

Tags: redcap

I'm seeking guidance on managing the redcap_repeat_instance field without pre-populating it in the JSON packets sent from an iOS app to a Redcap server. My concern arises from scenarios where a participant may uninstall and reinstall the app, potentially causing data overwrites. Similarly, reassigning devices to new participants risks overwriting previous participants' data.

Is there a method to auto-increment the redcap_repeat_instance value on the Redcap server side to prevent such issues? Using the epoch value is not a viable solution due to the constraint that redcap_repeat_instance must be a numeric value between '1' and '32767' for any Repeating Event or Instrument.

I appreciate any advice or solutions you can provide to navigate this challenge while ensuring data integrity and preventing overwrites.

Answer (score 0):

found the answer in this document https://cri.uchicago.edu/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/REDCap-11.1.7-New-Features-Improvements.pdf
simply assign it to "new" and it will auto-increment.